# Heroku: run npm install and gulp build for a Django app

Tags: django, heroku, npm, gulp

I have a Django app that I managed to deploy with Heroku. My `Procfile` file only contains :

```
web: gunicorn omegapp3.wsgi --log-file -
```

So when I run `heroku local` it works.

But when I deploy with `heroku push master`, the console detects a **Node app** because the app has a `package.json` and then the build fails.

What I would like to do is the following :

- run `npm install` to install `gulp` etc.
- run gulp build.

Do you know how I can do that ?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app), you should add **multiple** buildpacks to your setup, rather than a single *multi* buildpack.

For example, if you wanted to deploy an app that uses a Nodejs package (i.e. grunt, gulp, etc) to do some setup on your app, you would run this from your command line:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

The `add` command adds the Nodejs buildpack as an **additional** buildpack, rather than replacing your current buildpack.  Note the `--index 1`.  This specifies that the Nodejs buildpack is the first in the order of buildpacks.  This is important because the final buildpack is the one used for actual process type.  You can call `heroku buildpacks` from the command line to verify the buildpack setup.  I run a Python app, so my `heroku buildpacks` looks like this:

```
=== your_app_name_here Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

Then, as stated by rocketer, you can place this in your `package.json` file to be run on deploy:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp build"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using `$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`.
It allows to use `node` and `python` (you have to specify in a `.buildpacks` file). 
In ordre to run `gulp build`, I added the following to my `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp build"
}
```